# Is there an .htaccess visualizer like regex101.com?

Tags: web-server, apache

I like regex101.com for visualizing and helping with regex patterns, is there something like this for .htaccess files?

I am searching for something where I can put in my `.htaccess` content and an example URL. Then the tool shows me if there are any general errors in my `.htaccess` (typos etc.) and explanations which rule and command does what when the example URL is parsed.

The way like https://regex101.com does it for regex patterns is a good example for what I have in mind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to elaborate a little further.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Found it with a search of [".htaccess" tester online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22.htaccess%22%20tester%20online&ia=web)

According to a [post about this tool](https://churchm.ag/online-htaccess-tester/) with screenshots, it seems this is what you where looking for.

Comment: thanks, yes this is something like I meant it. Its just not very good because there are a lot of `This line is not supported by our tool.` and is not so much explained, but its already nice to see :)

Comment: I see, and I'm not clear of whether the web site, or the engine behind it is open-source. But they do have a [public issue tracker](https://github.com/madewithlove/htaccess.madewithlove.be/issues), not very active, but developer do seem to answer.
Pointing to their FOSS cli-api tool. In anyway, good luck, and if you find something more interesting, let us know here.